# Phonegap_event when application closes

Tags: javascript, cordova, events, dom-events

Is there an event that listens if app is closed?
I want to clear my localStorage when it closes.
So something like

```
document.addEventListener("applicationClose", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Or to erase it when app starts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using sessionStorage, it  is equal to the localStorage object, except that stores data for only one session